# Destroy does not destroy

Tags: python, tkinter

I do not understand the way destroy works...

I have a class SubWindow that is a subclass of Tk.Toplevel
If this subwindow has an internal widget

> self.label = Tk.Label(master=self, text='This is Sub Window:
>   %s!!!!'%self)

when I destroy the subwindow, it does not DIE, it sill alive (I know this looking at the array of subwindows)

The only way to destroy the subwindow is to call

> del self.label

in the destroy method.

```
import Tkinter as Tk
import weakref

root = Tk.Tk()
subwindows = []


def subwindow():
    subwindows.append(weakref.ref(SubWindow(root)))

def list_subwindows():
    print 'Subwindows: ',
    for subwindow in subwindows:
        sw = subwindow()
        if sw:
            print sw,
    print ''


class SubWindow(Tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, window):
        Tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master = window)
        self.label = Tk.Label(master=self, text='This is Sub Window: %s!!!!'%self)
        self.label.pack()
#        self.bind('<Destroy>', self._destroy)


    def _destroy(self, event):
        try:
            del self.label 
        except:
            pass


bStartWindow = Tk.Button(master=root, text='Start Sub Window', 
                         command=subwindow)
bStartWindow.pack()

bListSubwindows = Tk.Button(master=root, text='List Active subwindows',
                            command = list_subwindows)
bListSubwindows.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Why is the subwindow not destroyed when it has an internal widget?

Comment: How are you destroying this widget?

Comment: By your question, I guess I am doing it wrong, but I am just closing the window with the X button in the top right corner. I thought it was not necessary to call destroy() directly

Comment: Don't infer anything from my question. I asked simply because you didn't say how you were destroying it. The way you destroy determines what is happening. Clicking on the window decoration causes different things to happen than if you directly call the `destroy` method or if you call `del` on the widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way Tkinter is implemented, a widget such as a toplevel is actually two objects. It is an instance of a python class, and it is also an object in the sense that it is something that the underlying Tk library understands.

I haven't looked that closely, but I suspect the default binding for the window is to destroy the widget rather than to destroy the python class instance. So, the toplevel widget is destroyed, but the instance of `Subwindow` is not immediately destroyed. Or more accurately, it has been destroyed but not garbage-collected yet.

When a widget it destroyed, all of its child widgets are also destroyed. I'm not quite sure why you think the label is not being destroyed, because I don't see any code that is actually checking for the label widget. Why do you think the label isn't being destroyed?

What you are seeing is merely evidence that the garbage collector hasn't run. The widget has been destroyed but the Tkinter wrapper persists.

Modify `list_windows` to force garbage collection and you'll see that the object really was destroyed:

```
def list_subwindows():
    import gc
    gc.collect()
    print 'Subwindows: ',
    for subwindow in subwindows:
        sw = subwindow()
        if sw:
            print sw,
    print ''
```

Comment: If you run the code, you will see a window with two buttons, one that creates a subwindow and other that list active subwindows. The list of active subwindows list every subwindow object that still alive in the sense that is found by weakref

Comment: It is not the label that I am worried about, is the subwindow object that I want to be destroyed

Comment: @fariza: I've updated my answer. All you're seeing is evidence that the garbage collector hasn't run. The object has been destroyed, it just hasn't been GC'd when you click the button. Force a garbage collection and the objects will truly be gone (but only do that as a learning exercise; it isn't necessary to do it in a real app)

Comment: Thank you, Very interesting, but why does "del self.label" changes the behaviour of the garbage collector. It changes from inmediate to somewhere in the future, but far far far away